# What are the top 21 meetings regarding climate change?

Tags: climate-change

I was at an academic conference recently and one of the presenters mentioned examining certain variables before and after the top 21 climate change meetings.

Unfortunately I was not able to get a hold of her after the conference and I have no background in earth science/climate change. Does anyone know what she could have been referring to?

I am aware of the COP and CMP only held by the UN.

Answer (score 3):

As Isopcycnal Oscillation has noted in the comments, you've probably misheard, and what they were talking about was [COP 21](http://www.cop21paris.org/about/cop21) (not "top 21"), the 21<sup>st</sup> summit of the [UNFCCC](http://newsroom.unfccc.int/) parties in Paris, December 2016.